# Basic algebraic geometry from a modern point of view

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Due to some circumstances I ended up learning algebraic geometry from a very abstract point of view, without any exposure to more classical topics. I am now in the awkward situation where I am comfortable with concepts such as schemes, sheaves and cohomology, despite knowing very few examples.

Finding a more classical book and working through it would certainly help, but that seems like an inefficient approach. Therefore I am looking for a text on classical topics from a modern point of view, preferably with many exercises. (Prime example: Ch. 27 of Vakil's FoAG , about the 27 lines on a cubic.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also did you try chapter IV and V of Hartshorne's book ? It's pretty concrete and lot of useful computations are done.

Comment: Nicolas, thank you for the suggestion! I had given up on Hartshorne back when I started learning algebraic geometry, as I did not really like the exposition, so I forgot that it has applications to curves and surfaces in it. I will give it another try!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Dolgachev's "Classical Algebraic Geometry: a modern view" is a kind of book you may enjoy. It is freely available from the author's website:

http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/CAG.pdf

Comment: That might just be exactly what I'm looking for! I'll take a look at it soon. Thanks.